# Ejecutar función que viene de un string [JS][JQUERY]

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

tengo un pequeño problemas... Lo he intentado resolverlo pero no he podido!

El código es así

```
var menuarray = [
        // [div, name, function]
        ['#menu_user', 'Usuario', 'usuario.last()'],
        ['#mon_list', 'Monitor', 'notifica.last()'],
        ['#mp_list', 'Mensajes', 'mensaje.last()'],
        ['#fav_list', 'Favoritos', 'favorito.last()'],
        ['#shout_list', 'Shout', 'shout.last()']
    ]
    $('body').on('click', e => { 
        for(let menu = 0; menu < menuarray.length; menu++) {
            if (
                $(menuarray[menu][0]).css('display') != 'none' && 
                $(e.target).closest(menuarray[menu][0]).length == 0 && 
                $(e.target).closest(`a[name=${menuarray[menu][1]}]`).length == 0
            ) fn(menuarray[menu][2]);
        }
    });
```

Por lo que se debería ejecutar la función al hacer clic en cualquier parte del sitio, ejemplo `shout.last()`, pero no lo hace y me devuelve este error, lo he probado con `eval()`, pero no hace nada, ni siquiera pinta error

*Lo hice en string, por que si los agrego sin las comillas, estas funciones se auto-ejecutan*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado correctamente, y desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Y porqué no almacenas la función en ese Array? Usar `eval` no es aconsejable. Saludos

Comment: Ya lo había intentado pero se auto-ejecutan, por eso agregue las comillas!

Comment: Pues no les pongas los paréntesis. Simplemente la referencia a las mismas. Las ejecutarás a demanda, cuando las necesites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como digo en mi comentario, sólo debes guardar en el Array las referencias a las funciones que necesitas. Si añades los paréntesis las funciones se ejecutan (son llamadas), pero si no los agregas, entonces estás guardando una referencia a las mismas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const menuarray = [
        // [div, name, function]
        ['#menu_user', 'Usuario', usuario.last],
        ['#mon_list', 'Monitor', notifica.last],
        ['#mp_list', 'Mensajes', mensaje.last],
        ['#fav_list', 'Favoritos', favorito.last],
        ['#shout_list', 'Shout', shout.last]
];
$('body').on('click', e => { 
  for(let menu = 0; menu < menuarray.length; menu++) {
    if(
      $(menuarray[menu][0]).css('display') != 'none' &&
    
  $(e.target).closest(menuarray[menu][0]).length == 0 &&
 
     $(e.target).closest(`a[name=${menuarray[menu][1]}]`).length == 0
    ) menuarray[menu][2]();  // <= llamada
  }
});
```

Como se observa en el código, en la posición 2 del Array anidado dentro del Array de menú estoy guardando la referencia a la función apropiada. Si la condición dentro de la sentencia `if` se cumple, entonces se ejecuta la función, mediante el uso de paréntesis.

Obviamente, para que puedas llamar a las funciones de esta manera, las mismas deben existir en memoria, es decir, deben haber sido declaradas con anterioridad.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: No lo había pensado, lo probé y funciona! Gracias @MauricioContreras!

Answer (score 1):

Listo, la culpa fue mía... No me percate que que puse `menuarray[menu][3]` y este no existe, por ende no funciona, lo que debía haber puesto es esto `menuarray[menu][2]` y ya he podido solucionarlo

### OTRA SOLUCION FACTIBLE

```
var menuarray = [
        // [div, name, function]
        ['#menu_user', 'Usuario', 'usuario.last()'],
        ['#mon_list', 'Monitor', 'notifica.last()'],
        ['#mp_list', 'Mensajes', 'mensaje.last()'],
        ['#fav_list', 'Favoritos', 'favorito.last()'],
        ['#shout_list', 'Shout', 'shout.last()']
    ]
    $('body').on('click', e => { 
        for(let menu = 0; menu < menuarray.length; menu++) {
            if (
                $(menuarray[menu][0]).css('display') != 'none' && 
                $(e.target).closest(menuarray[menu][0]).length == 0 && 
                $(e.target).closest(`a[name=${menuarray[menu][1]}]`).length == 0
            ) {
                // Esto lo encontré en 
                // http://www.etnassoft.com/2011/01/05/javascript-eval-uso-y-alternativas/ (Método 2)
                var fnTemp = new Function(menuarray[menu][2]);
                fnTemp();
            }
        }
    });
```